# JTextArea doesn't work when Frame is split in two JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

I want split my Frame into two JPanel and the right JPanel serve as a textarea used to input and display.
However, I can't input anything in it and it can't display any thing.
the code as below:

```
JPanel jp1, jp2;
public DemoFrame() {
    jp1 = new JPanel();
    jp2 = new JPanel();
    JLabel label = new JLabel("text");
    JTextArea ta = new JTextArea(100,100);
    ta.setText("some text");
    ta.setSize(300, 300);
    jp2.add(label);
    jp2.add(ta);
    JSplitPane jsp = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT, jp1, jp2);
    this.getContentPane().add(jsp);;
    setBounds(300, 200, 500, 500);
    setVisible(true);
    jsp.setDividerLocation(0.5);// 
}
```

the output as below(it doesnt display anything):
[image]

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: `JTextArea ta = new JTextArea(10, 10);` should begin to hint at the mistake.. Note that the two integers passed to the constructor are not pixels, but columns and rows.

Comment: @ Hovercraft Full Of Eels Yeah, I get it. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Congratulations, you've fallen victim to a number of conspiring issues.

The main culprit is `FlowLayout`, which is the default layout manager for `JPanel`.  Essentially, when you add your, rather large, `JTextArea` to the panel, the `FlowLayout` is trying to honour the preferred size as best as it can within the constraints of the available space.  For reasons I'm not 100% sure of, that means laying out the component beyond the visible bounds of the container.

If you type enough text, you will begin to see it.

While there are a number of ways you might fix this, they are basically the same solution - use a different layout manager.

For this example, I've just used a `BorderLayout` instead

[image: Simple border layout]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JSplitPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    private JPanel jp1, jp2;

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
                jp1 = new JPanel();
                jp2 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
                JLabel label = new JLabel("text");
                JTextArea ta = new JTextArea(50, 50);
                ta.setText("some text");
                jp2.add(label, BorderLayout.NORTH);
                jp2.add(new JScrollPane(ta));
                JSplitPane jsp = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT, jp1, jp2);

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(jsp);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```